# UWP Get the hidden text in a text block

Tags: c#, windows-phone, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I have a long text and I set it to a textblock. Now I want to get the text which is hidden from the user. Is there any way to accomplish it in a UWP app?

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind is doing it "mathematically". Getting box's width, using a monospaced font and calculating what goes beyond the boundaries.

Comment: Could you please be more precised and provide more information? I am not sure what exactly you would like to achieve.

Comment: @danny I have explained my requirement below for Rachhek Shrestha 's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the **TextWrapping** Property of the **TextBlock** to Wrap. This will break the lines into required lines to show all the text. Just make sure you set required height of the TextBlock.

```
 <TextBlock Text="Heleoleleleleleoeleoeleoeleoeleoeoeleoeo"
               Width="100" 
               TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```

[image: Screenshot]
`

Comment: That's not what was asked.

Comment: I don't want to show all the text. If the text block can only have enough space to show "Heleolele" I want to know that "leleoeleoeleoeleoeleoeoeleoeo" is hidden from the user.. Thanks for your response